# "the Chinese and American people" VS "the Chinese and American peoples"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. The Chinese and American *people* are both great *people*.
> 2. The Chinese and American *peoples* are both great *peoples*.

Which kind of wording is good?

Answer (score 1):

People when meaning the population of a country or nation is a countable noun, thus:

2. The Chinese and American peoples are both great peoples.

> people 
>   noun [ C ]
>
> All the men, women, and children who live in a particular country, or who have the
>   same culture or language:
>
> The French are known as a food-loving people. ​
>
> a society:
>
> Customs similar to this one are found among many peoples of the world.

[People](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/people)